# Choosing specific rows and columns from numpy array

Tags: python

I have a numpy array with 26 rows and 26 columns. I want to select all rows except row 15 and all columns except column 15. Is there any way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(676).reshape((26,26))
```

the 15th row
    b = a[14]

and 15th column

```
c = a[:,14]
```

should both be removed from a.

Is it possible to do this by broadcasting? I don't want to delete the rows and columns and I don't want to make a new matrix by slicing the part I want and using vstack as i feel it is a less elegant solution. I would love to select everything else except b and c without changing the original array. thanks

Comment: Check out `delete` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(676).reshape((26,26))
```

First we need to define which rows we want:

```
index = np.arange(a.shape[0]) != 14 # all rows but the 15th row
```

we can use the same index for columns, since we are selecting the same rows and columns, and a is a square matrix

Now we can use np.ix_ function to express that we want all selected row and columns.

```
a[np.ix_(index, index)] #a.shape =(25, 25)
```

Note that a[index, index] won't work since only the diagonal elements will be selected (the result is an array not a matrix)

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical indexing

```
 row_index = 26 * [False]
 row_index[15] = True

 column_index = 26 * [True]
 colunn_index[15] = False

 myarray[row_index, column_index]
```

Comment: This is not how indexing works. The result is the diagonal elements with `a[15, 15]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete`:

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.arange(676).reshape((26,26))
new_array = np.delete(a, 14, 0) 
new_array = np.delete(new_array, 14, 1)
```

Reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Answer (score 0):

You can select all rows and columns except one by applying conditions. In your case you can select all the rows and columns except for the `15`th by

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(676).reshape((26,26))
x = np.arrange(26)
y = np.arrange(26)
c = a[x != 14, :]
c = c[:, y != 14]
```

This selects all rows and columns except for the 15th one.

Comment: i get x is not defined when i try this

Comment: My original matrix is 26x26, when i try to use your method i'm not sure what 'np' stands for in the last line because that gives me an error, i assume you're referring to the original matrix right?

Comment: `np` is the matrix in which you are trying to apply slicing. I have updated the answer according to your question.

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution exactly as it is but i get this error: 
 "main.py:5: VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 25 but corresponding boolean dimension is 26
  c = a[x != 14][y != 14]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    c = a[x != 14][y != 14]
IndexError: index 25 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 25"

Comment: Updated the answer again.